# Flip text with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had a button that rotated text along the Y axis , giving it a mirrored look.  This no longer works for some reason because the button has been placed on the child (popup) and the text to be mirrored is on the parent.

Is there a javascript function i could use to rotate the text on the parent when a button is clicked / rotate it back when its clicked again. (preferably a toggle switch)

This is what I originally had when it was only one the parent page:

HTML link :

```
       <li><a class="button small icon-text-height flipx" href="#" onclick="return false;"></a></li>
```

The CSS for the div with the text:

```
    article .teleprompter
{
    padding: 300px 50px 1000px 100px;
    font-size: 30px !important;
    line-height: 86px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #141414;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

The CSS for the flipx part:

```
article .teleprompter.flipx
{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    padding: 300px 50px 1000px 100px !important;
}
```

JS I Think should work:

```
    <script>
        function flipTXT(color)
    {
    if (parent_window && !parent_window.closed) {
    parent_window.document.getElementById("teleprompter").style['-webkit-transform'] = rotateY(180deg);
    }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What's the javascript you're using? Also, is the button going to live in the popup instead of the same page as the text?

Comment: @AlexMorales   well the original had no javascript . Iv editied my post with some javascript that I think would work with the parent child system i have now

Comment: What you can do is add and remove the class attribute accordingly instead of changing the style attribute. So if you want it to flip, add the .flipx class, and when you want it to display normally, remove it.

Comment: @AlexMorales  i dont really do javascript so I wouldn't know where to begin

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the two solutions seen in the code at Bin below may work for you:

http://jsbin.com/buqexusamuda/1/

HTML

```
<p>Card: Flip</p>
<div class="card" href="#">Hello</div>
<p>Card 2: Mirror</p>
<div class="card card2" href="#">Hello</div>
```

CSS

```
.card, .card2 {
  position: relative;
  animation: all 2.5s;
  perspective: 1000;  
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 90px;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 32px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #666;
}
.card2 { transform-origin: right center; }
.card.flip { transform: rotateY(180deg); }
```

SCRIPT

```
jQuery(".card").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("flip");
});
```

Comment: it dosent do anything?  Jquery is not defined

Comment: How would I make it so that i click a button and the text is flipped instead of clicking the text to flip it?

Comment: You need to include jQuery before the code above: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use jQuery to add/remove the classes. If you can include jQuery, then you can do something along these lines:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Since the text is on the parent, you need to access it.
    var parentWindow = window.opener;

    //This gets the parent's DOM so you can grab the text from the parent window.
    var parentDom = parentWindow.document;

    //This grabs the text you want to transform.
    var targetText = parentDom.getElementsByClassName("teleprompter");

    //This toggles the class
    $(".button").on('click', function(){
        $(targetText).toggleClass("flipx");
    });

});
</script>
```

I used a combination of jQuery and regular javascript so you don't have to roll your own code to add/remove and check for classes.

Here's the code to include jQuery in your page in case you don't have it handy:

This one will work with older non-HTML 5 compliant browsers and modern browsers.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This one will only work with more modern browsers:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Jamie - You need to paste the code to include jQuery into your html file. You can copy/paste all this code at the bottom of your page before the </body>. Just make sure you put the <script> tag that points to google in before the other code.